# if $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$, the integral basis of $O_K$ is $\{1, \sqrt d\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ be the quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $O_K$ be the ring of integers (free $\mathbb{Z}$-module), then

$(i)$ if $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$, the integral basis of $O_K$ is $\{1, \sqrt d\}$,

$(ii)$ if $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, the integral basis of $O_k$ is $\{1, \frac{1+\sqrt d}{2} \}$.

**Answer:**

I am having problem of choosing these bases. In the proof it is given that:

$(i)$ if $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$, then $a^2 \equiv b^2d \pmod 4$, $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, which indicate  either $a$ and $b$ must be even and hence $\{1, \sqrt d\}$ is an integral basis.

My question is how  the above logic shows $\{1, \sqrt d \}$ is a basis ?

Help me

Comment: ... *the* integral basis?  *An* integral basis!

Comment: Take $u+v \sqrt{d} \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ it is an algebraic integer iff $(x-(u+v \sqrt{d}))(x-(u-v \sqrt{d})) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: @reuns, Thanks for your nice answer. But can you help me why the logic in $(i)$ of my answer part proves $\{1, \sqrt d \}$ is a basis ?

Comment: It proves it because $(x-(u+v \sqrt{d}))(x-(u-v \sqrt{d})) \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ leads to several equations and they have simple solutions in term of $d \bmod 4$ (with $d$ square-free). Your book assumed you already knew that.